# How to nest content inside a flex box 'holy grail' layout?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

My goal is to build a 'Holy-Grail' based layout with flex. The main content area needs to have additional content.
[image: HolyGrail with nested content in main section]

I am having real trouble aligning the 'Upper Content Left, Upper Content Center, Upper Content Right, Middle Content, and Lower Content' alongside one another and filling the available space.

Here is a [**codepen**](http://codepen.io/mjankowski/pen/xEAEzj) I modified in an attempt to nest the content.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.page {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}
.contentMain {
  flex: 1;
  background: lightblue;
  min-width: 10em;
}
.nav,
.ads {
  /* 12em is the width of the columns */
  flex: 0 0 12em;
}
.nav {
  /* put the nav on the left */
  order: -1;
  background: salmon;
}
.ads {
  background: green;
}
header,
footer {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 4em 1em;
}
/*Nested Content*/

.ucleft {
  background-color: gray;
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
}
.uccenter {
  background-color: red;
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
}
.ucright {
  background-color: lightgray;
  width: 30%;
  float: right;
}
.middlecontent {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
}
.lowercontent {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- currently not working in IE, don't know why -->

<body class="page">
  <header>Header</header>
  <div class="content">
    <main class="contentMain">
      <div class="upperContainer">
        <div class="ucleft">UC Left</div>
        <div class="uccenter">UC Center</div>
        <div class="ucright">UC Right</div>
      </div>
      <div class="middlecontent">Middle Content</div>
      <div class="lowercontent">Lower Content</div>
    </main>
    <nav class="nav">Nav</nav>

  </div>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</body>
```

Comment: You're mixing floats with flex positioning is there a reason for this? Possible the upper left can use flex?

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to nest another flex in with the first...so I tried floats

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several ways to construct this layout. Here's just one:

- You don't need floats, so I removed them.
- You don't need `display: inline-block`. Also removed.
- You have an unnecessary container. Removed.

For this particular method, the five content items are wrapped in a `row wrap` flex container.

The first three items are given a width of 33.33%. The remaining items have a width of 100%.

This means the first three items will consume all the space in the first row, forcing the last two items to create additional rows.

*Tested in Chrome, Firefox, Edge and IE11.*

```css
.page {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0;
}
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 60vh;
}
.contentMain {
  flex: 1;
  background: lightblue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  /* default setting; can be omitted */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.nav, .ads {
  /* 12em is the width of the columns */
  flex: 0 0 12em;
}
.nav {
  /* put the nav on the left */
  order: -1;
  background: salmon;
}
.ads {
  background: green;
}
header, footer {
  flex: 0 0 20vh;
  background: #ccc;
}

/*Nested Content*/
.ucleft {
  flex: 1 0 33.33%;
  background-color: gray;
}
.uccenter {
  flex: 1 0 33.33%;
  background-color: red;
}
.ucright {
  flex: 1 0 33.33%;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
.middlecontent {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}
.lowercontent {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<body class="page">
  <header>Header</header>
  <div class="content">
    <main class="contentMain">
      <div class="ucleft">UC Left</div>
      <div class="uccenter">UC Center</div>
      <div class="ucright">UC Right</div>
      <div class="middlecontent">Middle Content</div>
      <div class="lowercontent">Lower Content</div>
    </main>
    <nav class="nav">Nav</nav>
  </div>
  <footer>Footer</footer>
</body>
```

[**revised codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RGgoaN)

Comment: This is great! Just what I need! Thank you! How would I vary the heights of the content areas?

Comment: With the `height` property. Depending on what you want to do, use pixels, ems, vh, etc..

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example with a nested flex to correctly position the upper row (no floats or inline, just flex!):

**Demo:** http://codepen.io/aaronvanston/pen/XjgNjP

The upper row can have as many columns with inside it and it will automatically adjust the widths.

It has a sticky footer as yours does.

The HTML is relatively simple:

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

.nav {
  flex: 0 0 12em;
}

.content {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  flex-direction: row;
  
}
.col {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}

/* TEMP CODE FOR THIS TEST, REMOVE FOR ACTUAL USE
*/
body {
  text-align: center;
}

*{
  box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 1px #f00;
}
```

```html
<header clas="header">Header</header>
<main class="main">
  <nav class="nav">
    Nav
  </nav>
  <section class="content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        Upper Left
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        Upper Middle
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        Upper Right
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      Middle
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      Lower
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
<footer class="footer">Footer</footer>
```

Comment: This is a great answer.